# xHTML two column table

Tags: xslt

I'm pulling my hair out on this one, likely because I'm new to XSL. I had been using JavaScript but XSL seems to do the job better except for one thing.

I want to use table instead of div because I need the cells to be the same height on a given row. I can do this with divs using `display:table` but it really leaves me with the same problem - getting the rows in the right place.

The working templates as submitted by Abel are:

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="club[position() mod 2 = 1]" mode="row" />
    </tbody>
  </table>

    <xsl:template match="club" mode="row">
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::club | following-sibling::club[1]" mode="cell" />
      </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="club" mode="cell">
      <td class="club">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="content" />
      </td>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::club" mode="last" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="club" mode="content">
      <!-- a whole bunch of xsl to format a club -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="club[last()][position() mod 2 = 1]" mode="last">
      <td class="club"></td>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="last" />
```

This is a very nice solution to the problem of two-column tables (should be easily extensible to more columns).

In my application, I removed the class for "last" because the "club" td has a border which I didn't like for an empty cell. Simply removing the "last" template also works but leaves you with a row with only one td, which doesn't fit with my sense of aesthetics (not sure if it is even correct xhtml).

Thanks Abel. I don't have enough posts to up-rank your answer, but it was a very nice piece of work.

Comment: Hi Gary, could you post a sample of the XML so we can see the structure

Comment: What is the problem? The every other club? That is certainly what you request as position() mod 2 = 1. Or something else? Please be more specific in what your problem is.

Comment: Or think of your context ,,, the template named ClubRow has a context of club. I believe you think it has a different context because you use following-sibling::*/club .. is club a child of club?

Comment: The XML is irrelevant. The information one needs is in the XSL, which shows that the each "club" is a child of "clubs". As per my comments, the code is working for the odd-numbered "club" nodes but I'm getting no output for the even-numbered one. The issue is apparently one of the template not being applied to the following-sibling. The whole point of my question is how to get the context for the second apply-templates in the clubRow template to refer to the next club. As I said, I can modify the following sibling details and get every following sibling in the right-hand column. Still wrong.

Comment: "*The XML is irrelevant. The information one needs is in the XSL*" No, **the XML is very much relevant** here. Your XSLT does not work - so obviously at least *some* "information one needs" is wrong or missing. If you don't provide a way to [reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the problem, you are asking people to guess.

Comment: Abel was able to figure it out. The issue is in the way I was trying to get the next sibling. You don't need XML for that. Abel did go above and beyond by rewriting the application and pointing out my misunderstanding of xsl, so that I just needed to cut and paste and can now use the information he provided in future applications.

Comment: @GaryDale "*Abel was able to figure it out.*" No, Abel made a lucky guess (said so himself). I don't know why you keep arguing about this. The first step towards solving a problem is to reproduce it. That's not just my opinion. In fact, the rules of this site require you to enable us to do do: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: He made an educated guess. The problem didn't require the xml, just being able to read the problem title and the xsl code I'd posted. Similarly, his solution didn't require any more detail than what was obvious from the xsl - that there were clubs and that I wanted to print two clubs per column. You seem to believe that "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem" means including data whereas I believe that the generic nature of this problem - producing two-column tables - doesn't require it. If it was any other language, I wouldn't submit data on a programming issue.

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question. You can post the answer on its own, and even accept it. That is the proper indication  for others with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't give XML input, the following is a bit of an educated guessing game. Your code shows a `mod 2` and then calls a `clubRow` template, which suggests that you want two club elements in each row (this also follows from your question title).

And since you use `following-sibling`, this suggests that all club elements are siblings of one another. My guess is then that your source looks something like this:

```
<clubs>
    <club>Club 1</club>
    <club>Club 2</club>
    <club>Club 3</club>
    <club>Club 4</club>
    <club>Club 5</club>
</clubs>
```

Where 1 & 2, 3 & 4 go in one row each, and 5 has its own row with an empty last cell (in your code the `xsl:otherwise`).

If you were using XSLT 2.0, I'd choose `xsl:for-each-group` with positional grouping, but you don't say anything about what version or what vendor you are using, so I'll stay on the safe side and use vendor-neutral XSLT 1.0.

It looks to me that your idea is generally sound, but as was noticed in the comments, you are mixing the context item and seem to be at a loss between named and matching templates.

Try something like the following (css is mine, to show the effect):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/clubs">
        <table><tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="club[position() mod 2 = 1]" mode="row" />
        </tbody></table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="club" mode="row">
        <tr>
            <!-- apply current and next club -->
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="self::club | following-sibling::club[1]" 
                mode="cell" />
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="club" mode="cell">
        <td class="club">
            <!-- if you have structured content and further processing, use 
                 apply-templates here instead and add more matching templates 
                 in the mode "cell"  -->
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </td>
        <!-- re-apply in case this is the last club -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::club" mode="last" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- the last, if and only if it is uneven -->
    <xsl:template match="club[last()][position() mod 2 = 1]" mode="last">
        <td class="club"></td>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- ignore other clubs that are not last -->
    <xsl:template match="node()" mode="last" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces, with the given input, the following:

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
}

td {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

td.club {
  padding: .5em;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td:empty {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="club">Club 1</td>
  <td class="club">Club 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="club">Club 3</td>
  <td class="club">Club 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="club">Club 5</td>
  <td class="club" ></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Thanks Abel. You've added to my knowledge of XSL. Didn't know about mode, applying multiple templates to the same node or referring to multiple nodes in the select. I've updated the initial question to show how I've used your code - I think it's identical to what you listed but it's giving me just one column with every club shown. For some reason I've also lost the border around each cell and when I add "empty" to the last (even) cell, it doesn't show up even though the XML file has an odd number of "club"s. Is there a way I can direct the output to a file so I can see the xhtml code output?

Comment: OK, got it. Had to change the mode of the real club content to be unique. Thanks!

Comment: @GaryDale: _" Is there a way I can direct the output to a file"_ >> yes, that is the default for most [XSLT processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT#Processor_implementations), just run it from the commandline or in oXygen, Stylus Studio or Atova. I understand that you resolved the rest of your issues. Note that for `<td></td>` to be rendered correctly in a browser, it must not be output as `<td />` (while correct XML, browsers misinterpret it), which in XSLT 1.0 can only be achieved with output method `html`, in XSLT 2.0 with output method `xhtml`.

Comment: @GaryDale: if my answer helped you, feel free to upvote it and/or accept it as an answer ;).